# Determination and Impermanence

Tags: impermanence, paramitas

How can we have determination with this impermanent world, if determination is one of the paramitas?

"*I will do that thing (A) whatever happens*" is determination. But something else (B) can happen on the way that makes (A) a useless thing.

So, how can I have determination in the right way?

Answer (score 1):

The mind & all mental things are impermanent. When the body ends its life, the mind also is impermanent.

But during life, for a Fully Enlightened One, the virtues of the mind are permanent.

The Buddha said of himself:

> I am now old, aged, burdened with years, advanced in life, and come to
>   the last stage: my years have turned eighty... Sariputta, even if you
>   have to carry me about on a bed, still there will be **no change in
>   the lucidity of the Tathagata's wisdom**.
>
> MN 12

Answer (score 1):

In accordance with dhamma there are four kinds of resolve (adhitthanani):

> to gain (a) wisdom, (b) truth (sacca), (c) relinquishment (caga), (d) tranquility (upasama)

[DN33](http://www.suttas.com/dn-33-sangiti-sutta-the-chanting-together.html#)

Needless to say, this is contrary to many contemporary cultural ideals like social status, material gain, achievements or accomplishments.